# C++ unresolved externals when calling static variable

Tags: c++, static, scope, extern

I am trying to change a static variable inside a DLL, so when the extern function "ChangeVar" is called it will change the static variable. My problem is I can't get anything to compile. All of the code below is in a single C++ project compiled into a single DLL. I have no problems calling the function, as long as I don't try to change or get the static variable.

### Static.h

```c++
class API
 {
   public:
     static int iValue;
 };
```

### Functions.cpp

```c++
#include "Static.h"
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) bool ChangeVar()
    {
        API::iValue = 0;
        if(API::iValue == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this I just two errors:

```
Error  1  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int API::iValue" (?iValue@API@@2HA)
Error  2  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What do I need to do to create a static variable (clearly my way does not work), and how would I modify it so that it works like static should, where its value will be changed in memory?

Comment: The definition of API::iValue can't be inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered by a [SO C++ FAQ entry](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/faq#toc4): you've declared the variable but not defined it. You have to add

```
int API::iValue = 0;
```

Somewhere in a source file to define it.

Also, your test

```
if (API::iValue == 0)
```

will always evaluate to true because you set it to 0 just before testing if it equals 0, and the function will always return `true`.

Comment: Ok I did what you said, and it all compiles, but I now have two functions. One that increases the value by 1, and another function that gets the current value. No matter how many times I change it, when i pull the value its never changes. Even If I change it RIGHT before the if statement, it still returns false if I do == 0.

Comment: @user1078510 you'll have to update the code in your question with the code you're talking about

Comment: Sorry, I got it to work. It turns out for what ever reason even though I returned true or false, my C# would always get back true. the C++ code was fine. Thanks you sir!